# htaccess redirect not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

so I have this htaccess entry:

```
RedirectMatch /([a-zA-Z0-9]+).php /dirA/$1.php
```

The goal is that any .php that is on the root directory should be redirected to /dirA/*.php

eg. suppose I make the request

domain.com/something.php

it should instead redirect to

domain.com/dirA/something.php

However when I put that entry in my .htaccess file and then I go to domain.com/something.php

it instead returns

> "The page isn't redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
> this address in a way that will never complete."

Any idea how I can modify my htaccess to accomplish what I want to do?

### Updated Question

Also is there a way to make it so that it only redirects if the file doesn't exist in the root directory...hence if x.php exists in root, serve that x.php otherwise redirect to dirA/x.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mod_rewrite is an overkill for this, you were on the right track with `RedirectMatch`. Your rule, however, is a bit faulty: the regex `/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).php` matches all string that contain the specified substring, so it matches "/foo/bar/baz.php", but also "dirA/foo/bar.php" (and even "/foo/bar.php/baz.php"I. Your redirection ended up in an endless loop because there was no stop condition: /dirA/foo.php was redirected to /dirA/foo.php.

You can remedy the situation by using [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) in the regex:

```
RedirectMatch ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).php$ /dirA/$1.php
```

As for your second question: that might indeed call for mod_rewrite. Something along these lines should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).php$ /dirA/$1.php [R=301]
```

I haven't tested it, but this should get you started. Make sure to check out the [manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for details, or just search around on SO, there are tons of questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+).php /dirA/$1.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: so I did that and it redirected to /dirA/something.php which is fine but then when I changed dirA to my own directory and saved the htaccess, it's still redirecting to dirA....any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

This one should be just fine

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1`